Right side of assignment cannot be destructured ./node_modules/tronweb/lib/commonjs/utils/transaction.js
I've been battlng with tronweb for 4days now, same error flying here and there.
I've ran their verson from 5.3.2 - 6.0.0-beta.4
Errror 1.
Right side of assignment cannot be destructured
./node_modules/tronweb/lib/commonjs/utils/transaction.js
Error 2.
Cannot destructure property 'Transaction' of 'globalThis.TronWebProto' as it is undefined.
at ./node_modules/tronweb/lib/commonjs/utils/transaction.js
pls i just need help
creating TRC-20 wallet and making transactions

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

*This is a problem caused by webpack as it doesn't load cjs file correctly. To solve this problem, you need to add a new rule like below.
Install craco package to rewrite webpack without React project ejection:
npm install craco
Create file craco.config.js document in the root folder:
Put this code into it:
module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    configure: (webpackConfig) => {
      // Add the new rule for .cjs files
      webpackConfig.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.cjs$/,
        type: 'javascript/auto',
      });
      return webpackConfig;
    },
  },
};

Change starting scripts in package.json:
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "craco eject"
  },

*Solution from official TronWeb docs (https://tronweb.network/docu/docs/6.0.0-beta.3/Release%20Note/)
